# Minified React error #130 when building react module

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting

> Minified React error #130

when i import my react module to another application maybe the module build is wierd or not correct.

I referenced a similar question.

[Uncaught Error: Minified React error #130](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51803969/uncaught-error-minified-react-error-130)

but i think i have it set up correctly.

**src/Fetch**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import MyFetch from './MyFetch';
const Fetch = (props) => (
     <div>
       <form onSubmit={props.onSubmit}>
            <input type="text" value={props.url} placeholder="enter a url" onChange={props.onChange}/>
        </form>
          <MyFetch url={props.url} method={props.method}/>
     </div>
)
export default Fetch;
```

**src/index.js**

```
import Fetch from './Fetch';

export default Fetch
```

**dist/index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render} from 'react-dom';
import Fetch from '../src'
const App = () => (
    <Fetch />
);
render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const htmlWebpackPlugin = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: path.join(__dirname, "dist/index.html"),
    filename: "./index.html"
});
module.exports = {
    entry: path.join(__dirname, "dist/index.js"),
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, './'),
      filename: 'index.js',
   },
    module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.js$/,

            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components|build)/,
            use: {
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              options: { 
                presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/react'],
                plugins:['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties']
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
    plugins: [htmlWebpackPlugin],
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".js", ".jsx"]
    },
    devServer: {
        port: 3001
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

fixed it

```
plugins: [htmlWebpackPlugin,new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
          NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('development')
      }
  })]
```

[React - Minified exception occurred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29586928/react-minified-exception-occurred)